# Conditionally set image on a button in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

It is possible to conditionally show an image on a button in Xamarin Forms, within a dynamically populated ListView?

For instance, and to summarize, I've a button of a heart that needs to be filled red if a condition is true in the code behind, but otherwise not red.

```
<ListView x:Name="FullNamesList"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      ItemSelected="FullNamesList_OnItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.1*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label FontSize="Medium"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                       Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Label.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Gender}" Value="F">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#cc0066" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Gender}" Value="M">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#007acc" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Gender}" Value="A">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#00994d" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Label.Triggers>
                                </Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ShortMeaning}"
                                       FontSize="Small"
                                       TextColor="Gray"
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Grid.Column="1" />

                                <Button Image="favorite.png"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Grid.Column="2"
                                       Scale=".9" 
                                       Opacity=".3"
                                       ClassId="{Binding Name}"
                                       Clicked="FavoriteHeart_OnClicked"
                                       x:Name="favoriteHeart">

                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

When the page is initially constructed, I will iterate over a list. If the name is present in the list, I will need the image changed to `Button Image="favoritered.png"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace you `Button Image="Favorite.png"` for a binding.

```
<Button Image="{Binding FavoriteImage}"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="2"
           Scale=".9" 
           Opacity=".3"
           ClassId="{Binding Name}"
           Clicked="FavoriteHeart_OnClicked"
           x:Name="favoriteHeart">
```

An then in some place in your ViewModel:

Declare a `FavoriteImage` Binding and after that set a value to this variable

```
foreach(element in list){
    if(!string.isEmpty(element.NameVariable)){
        FavoriteImage = "favoriteded.png";
    }else{
        FavoriteImage = "favorite.png";
    }
}
```